# Sample a specific number of elements from a list with matching probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, sampling

Say I have a list of $n$ elements, $x=[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, and a list of $n$ probabilities $p=[p_i]$. I want to sample $c$ elements of the list without replacement, where $1<c<n$, and I want the probability that my sample contains $x_i$ to be $p_i$. This in turn means $\sum_i p_i=c$. Note that the $p_i$ are indeed probabilities, not weights: if $p_7=1$ then every sample must contain $x_7$.

For $n=3$, $c=2$ this problem is over-constrained and has a solution (let $p_{ij}$ be the probability of the specific sample $\{x_i,x_j\}$, then solve $\sum_{i,j}p_{ij}=1$, $p_{12}+p_{13}=p_1$, etc. Alternatively, notice that "pick a sample of two" is the same as "pick a sample of one and then choose the other two" and hence $p_{12}=1-p_3$, etc). This generalizes to $c=n-1$.

For $n=4$, $c=2$, the above system is under-constrained: a valid solution could have e.g. $p_i>0$ but also $p_{24}=p_{34}=0$.

My questions are:

1. Is there an existing algorithm for this sort of sampling, which has nice properties and avoids ruling out specific samples unnecessarily?
2. If not, are there any extra constraints I could put on the $n>c+1$ cases to force a unique solution?

   - Ideally this would be a constraint which pushes $p_{ij}$ to be closer to uniform or independent, however $p_{ij}=p_i p_j$ is too strong. Are there other obvious choices?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This does not always work, because sometimes it produces negative probabilities.

Here is a solution which seems pretty nice. For any $S\subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$, where $|S|=c$, the probability of choosing $S$ is as follows:
$$
\mathrm P(S)
=\frac1{(n-c)\binom{n-1}{c-1}}
\left({(n-c)\sum_{i\in S}p_i-(c-1)\sum_{j\notin S}p_j}\right)
$$
For example, the $n=4,c=3$, so that $n-c=\color{blue}{1}$ and $c-1=\color{red}2$, then
$$
\mathrm P(1,2,4)=\frac{\color{blue}1\cdot p_1+\color{blue}1 \cdot p_2-\color{Red}2\cdot p_3+\color{blue}1\cdot p_4}{3}
$$
When $n=5,c=2$,
$$
\mathrm P(2,5)=\frac{-p_1+3p_2-p_3-p_4+3p_5}{12}
$$
When $n=5,c=3$,
$$
\mathrm P(1,3,5)=\frac{2p_1-2p_2+2p_3-2p_4+2p_5}{12}
$$

Comment: Nice indeed! Could you walk me through your derivation? There's some obvious "breadcrumbs" but the intuition doesn't jump out at me.

Comment: Relatedly, is there a short description of a property you're preserving here which crisply distinguishes your solution from the under-constrained non-solution in my original question?

Comment: There is nothing that makes this a canonical or preferred solution. I just looked at the $n=3$ solution, which was $P(1,2)=(p_1+p_2-p_3)/2$, etc, and wondered if that pattern could generalize. So I sought solutions of the form
$$
\mathrm P(S)=A\cdot\sum_{i\in S}p_i -B\sum_{j\notin S}p_j
$$
for constants $A,B$. The sum of $\mathrm P(S)$ over all $S$ which contain $i$ must equal $p_i$. Applying that to the above, you can show that choosing $A$ and $B$ in the ratio $n-c$ to $c-1$ causes the massive cancellations you need. The denominator happened to be the correct normalization constant.

Comment: Ok, since $\sum_{i\not\in S}p_i=c-\sum_{i\in S}p_i$, we can also phrase your solution as the unique solution where $P(S)=a\sum_{i\in S}p_i + b$. In that formulation, $a={n-2 \choose c - 1}^{-1}$ and $b=-(c-1){n-1 \choose c}^{-1}$.

Comment: ...which isn't admissible, because it sometimes gives negative probabilities (e.g. let $p_2=p_5=0$ in your $n=5,c=2$ example). Damn.

Comment: Ah, too bad! OK, I have a different method which is a bit harder to describe, and certainly way less "nice", but it provably produces a solution. It'll take me some days to write up.

Comment: @eapi It turns out that my alternate idea did not pan out :(

Comment: Dang, I haven't had any luck either. Thanks though!